# Double free in my destruct function

Tags: c, memory-leaks, compiler-errors, segmentation-fault, free

I am currently trying to free everything from my program and keep getting a double free problem. I will first show you my construct function:

```
table_t *table_construct (int table_size, int probe_type)
{
    int i;
    table_t *hash;
    if(table_size < 1) return NULL;

    hash = malloc(sizeof(table));
    hash->table = malloc(sizeof(list*) * table_size);
    for(i=0; i < table_size; i++)
    {
        hash->table[i] = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
        hash->table[i]->K = 0;
        hash->size++;
    }
    //hash->size = table_size;
    hash->probing_type = probe_type;
    hash->key_entries = 0;
    return hash;
}
```

I am creating a hash table and malloc an array. I then at the end of my program use this destruct function:

```
void table_destruct (table *hash)
{
    int i;
    list *list, *temp;

    if(hash == NULL) return;

    for(i=0; i<hash->size; i++)
    {
        list = hash->table[i];
        while(list !=NULL)
        {
            temp = list;
            //list = list->next;
            free(temp);
        }
    }
    free(hash->table);
    free(hash);
}
```

I go through the array freeing all the slots that I malloced then delete the whole thing. When I run it I get this error:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./prog: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x000000000223e2f0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7eb96)[0x7f57f6086b96]
./prog[0x400bbf]
./prog[0x4032d0]
./prog[0x4014fb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7f57f602976d]
./prog[0x4009e9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00406000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 272335                          
00606000-00607000 r--p 00006000 08:01 272335                             
00607000-00608000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 272335                             
0223e000-0225f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f57f5df2000-7f57f5e07000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3411537                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f57f5e07000-7f57f6006000 ---p 00015000 08:01 3411537                    /lib/x86_64linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f57f6006000-7f57f6007000 r--p 00014000 08:01 3411537                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f57f6007000-7f57f6008000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 3411537                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f57f6008000-7f57f61bd000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3417211                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f57f61bd000-7f57f63bc000 ---p 001b5000 08:01 3417211                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f57f63bc000-7f57f63c0000 r--p 001b4000 08:01 3417211                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f57f63c0000-7f57f63c2000 rw-p 001b8000 08:01 3417211                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f57f63c2000-7f57f63c7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f57f63c7000-7f57f64c2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3417221                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7f57f64c2000-7f57f66c1000 ---p 000fb000 08:01 3417221                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7f57f66c1000-7f57f66c2000 r--p 000fa000 08:01 3417221                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7f57f66c2000-7f57f66c3000 rw-p 000fb000 08:01 3417221                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7f57f66c3000-7f57f66e5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3417227                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f57f68cf000-7f57f68d2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f57f68e1000-7f57f68e5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f57f68e5000-7f57f68e6000 r--p 00022000 08:01 3417227                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f57f68e6000-7f57f68e8000 rw-p 00023000 08:01 3417227                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7fff79fe9000-7fff7a00a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff7a0e6000-7fff7a0e7000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I can not find out what my problem is. Any thing I am not seeing?

Comment: I had it there but commented it out because after looking at it, it didnt make sense logically to me. Was I right the first time?

Comment: The problem is you don't need the while loop at all

Comment: I got the same error with it and it didnt make sense logically after drawing it out so I commented it out

Comment: Im sorry but what do you mean by that?

Comment: Okay taking out the while loop solved that problem much thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destruct simply needs to be:

```
void table_destruct (table_t *hash)
{
    int i;

    if (hash == NULL) 
       return;

    for (i=0; i<hash->size; i++)
    {
        free(hash->table[i];);
    }
    free(hash->table);
    free(hash);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0; i<hash->size; i++)
{
    list = hash->table[i];
    while(list !=NULL)
    {
        temp = list;
        //list = list->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

You are never assigning `list = NULL`, so, `while` condition remains `true` and it enters the loop again to `free` the `list`, you have just `free'd`.

Comment: Perhaps a little late? ... And while true, not actually the answer.

Comment: @MitchWheat:: Oh...I thought that there was the cause for double freeing. Would you please explain the concept a little? Was it beacuse, the OP was assigning "list = hash->table[i];" ?